# Create journal database: is there any easy way to auto-download all the citations of a volume or all the volumes of a journal?

Tags: citations, databases

I am trying to create my own research database. The first step for me to do is to identify the journals that I need to read and refer to. The way I create the searching database is by copying all the articles' titles and authors one by one, or downloading the EndNote citation format and input it into the EndNote database. I found this process very time-consuming and wonder if there are ways to download all the citations of a volume/journal at one time or a few times?

Thank you!

Comment: Bulk downloading of articles (and likely citations) is against the terms of service of most journals. And no, you don't really need your own giant database - it already exists from each journal or something like Web of Science. You need a database of those articles that you have actually read and understood, which is a much smaller number.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes. I have a database for that. This is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Most journals deposit metadata at [CrossRef](https://www.crossref.org/), and CrossRef offers an API for accessing these data.

To access journal-level data, you need the journal's ISSN. You can find it on the journal's  website.

For instance, to access the metadata of the journal *International Organization* (ISSN 1531-5088), you can look at: 
https://api.crossref.org/journals/1531-5088 (You should use a [JSON-Beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) to format the text).

Look at [CrossRef's API Documentation](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) to find out how to fetch the journal-level data you wish to get.

Just as an example, if you modify the URL to this one: https://api.crossref.org/journals/1531-5088/works?sort=issued&order=desc&filter=from-online-pub-date:2020-01&select=author,DOI,title,references-count - - then you will see all articles from the journal *International Organization* issued since January 2020, and for each article you will only see those metadata that you selected in the URL, i.e. the author name, the DOI, the title of the paper, and the number of references the paper contains.

Good luck.